# Why did the query run so long in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I run a query on the really small amount of intraday GA data (about 166 rows).

```
SELECT pagePath
FROM `dataset_id.ga_sessions_intraday_*`
WHERE pagePath NOT IN (SELECT pagePath FROM `dataset_id.ga_sessions_intraday_*` WHERE type = 'EVENT') AND Type = 'PAGE'
```

After running the query, there was a counter: "Query running (792.7s)..." that kept going up and up. By 3000 s, I accidentally refreshed the windows in the browser and now there is even no sign of the query that was running in Query History.

Why did it take so much time to run the query? Why is the query not available in the Query History?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used wildcard which means you were querying ALL `ga_sessions_intraday_*` tables in `dataset_id` dataset which potentially a reason of lengthy run

Another point of slowness is not optimal below WHERE clause

```
WHERE pagePath NOT IN (SELECT pagePath 
  FROM `dataset_id.ga_sessions_intraday_*` WHERE type = 'EVENT')
```

you should rather use

```
WHERE pagePath NOT IN (SELECT pagePath 
  FROM `dataset_id.ga_sessions_intraday_*` WHERE type = 'EVENT' GROUP BY pagePath)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. The sum of rows in both intraday tables was 166, so I don't think it is a reason for the query being slow, and eventually not appearing in the query history.